# Select Columns to return when joining a table with Zend\Db\Sql

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db

I just want to return one column (per.cd_acao), so I tried something like:

```
$select->from(array('act' => 'tb_acao'))
           ->join(array('per' => 'tb_perfil_acao'),
                'per.cd_acao = act.cd_acao',
                array('cd_acao'),
                $select::JOIN_INNER
            );
```

but this is producing a query string like: 
    SELECT "act".*, "per"."cd_acao" AS "cd_acao" FROM "tb_acao" AS "act" INNER JOIN "tb_perfil_acao" AS "per" ON "per"."cd_acao" = "act"."cd_acao" WHERE "per"."sq_perfil" = '89'

it is bringing all columns from the first table, when I want none. What am I missing here?

Update

summarizing: When I don't inform 'columns' in a select object, it defaults to return all columns to me. But when I'm joining, I don't want any columns to be returned by the first table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An empty array will suffice

```
$select->from(array('act' => 'tb_acao'))
           ->columns(array())
           ->join(array('per' => 'tb_perfil_acao'),
                'per.cd_acao = act.cd_acao',
                array('cd_acao'),
                $select::JOIN_INNER
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
```

---

```
protected $tableGateway;
public $adapter;

public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
{
    $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
}

publice function getData(){
    $adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
    $sql = new Sql($adapter);
    $select = $sql->select();
    $select->from('tb_acao')
       ->join('per'),
            'per.cd_acao = act.cd_acao',
            array('cd_acao'),
        );
    $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
    $results = $statement->execute();

    return $results;
}
```